# how to safeguard this file upload in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically this is for a simple site where admin only will upload  pictures, how do i safeguard image upload here ?

```
        $uploaddir = "./images/";
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile) ;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO entries(cat_id, dateposted, subject,image,youtube,page, body)
                        VALUES(
                        '" .is_int($_POST['cat']) . "'
                        , mysql_real_escape_string(NOW())
                        ,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']) . "'
                        ,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['name'])."'
                        ,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youtube']) . "'
                        ,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page']) . "'
                        ,'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']) . "'
                        );";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What do you mean by safeguard? Do you want others not to have access to the files, or do you want to prevent specific files from being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your forgot make chmod at uploaded (moved) file (chmod -x !)
2. Your need rename uploaded file, i prefer [a-z\d-_.] + timestamp()
3. Your need check if file size is lower than maximum, allowed
4. Need check against allowed extension list $est in_array($config_fileupload_allowed)
5. this list is longer :) i check also content of files, i.e jpeg against signature, txt against symbols, so on.

This one code allow upload test.php file with something like

```
<?
  `rm -rf /`; 
?>
```

inside ...

PS.

```
mysql_real_escape_string(NOW())
```

this is extra, just use now(), why need escape it ...

,Arsen